# Connecting rails server from local machine to network

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ubuntu, localhost

I have made a rails application using 4.2.0 in my local Ubuntu machine. I want to deploy that application to local network of my campus. How can I do that?

I checked my ip from ifconfig, and deployed the webrick server via binding that ip and different ports too,

```
rails server -b my_ip -p port
```

the console says that the application is running in that ip and port but when I am trying to connect it via my browser, I get service timout error. Can anybody suggest me a method to do that?

Answer (score 3):

Binding to 0.0.0.0 tells the service to bind to all IP addresses on your machine. Rails server used to do this by default, but with 4.2 changed to binding only to localhost.

Basically if it's only bound to localhost then it will only respond locally to either localhost or 127.0.0.1 which can't work through a DNS service because it's not a public IP address.

When you use 0.0.0.0 it will bind to localhost and to your routable IP address.
Use rails s -b 0.0.0.0

Comment: no, still service not available. Is there any firewall block problem ?

Comment: No, sorry this worked. Thanks. I was just stuck in the proxy bypass in my local network